# Неудовлетворенные зависимости пакетов Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, зависимости

Неожиданно появившаяся проблема, apt --fix-broken install - не помогает

> Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:

```
 gtk2-engines-murrine : Ломает: gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 (!= 0.98.2-3) но 0.98.2-2 должен быть установлен
 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 : Зависит: libatk1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.12.4) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.2.4) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.12) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.0) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.37.3) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libpango-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.14.0) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.14.0) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.14.0) но он не будет установлен
                             Зависит: libpixman-1-0:i386 (>= 0.30.0) но он не будет установлен
                             Рекомендует: murrine-themes:i386 (>= 0.98) но он не может быть установлен
                             Ломает: gtk2-engines-murrine (!= 0.98.2-2) но 0.98.2-3 должен быть установлен'''
```

Comment: Обновите список пакетов `sudo apt update`

Comment: Ошб:22 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos//x86_64  Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 152.199.20.126 443]
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово            
W: Цель Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) настроена несколько раз: в /etc/apt/sources.list:46 и в /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Цель Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) настроена несколько раз: в /etc/apt/sources.list:46 и в /etc/apt/sources.list:61

Comment: Ну и? Теперь зависимости не ломаются? Что касается ошибки с пакетами Nvidia, то вам нужно поправить ссылку на https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/ . Эта ссылка либо в /etc/apt/sources.list либо в одном из файлов в каталоге /etc/sources.list.d/

Comment: При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04_i386.deb
проблема видимо тут

Answer (score 0):

Частично решил проблему отключением обновления репозиториев nvidia & cuda:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]